# How to make the Start button smaller when "Use small icons" is enabled for the taskbar

Tags: windows-7, windows, taskbar, icons

On Windows 7 there is an option under Properties for the Taskbar called "Use small icons" which will make the Taskbar a little more narrow and, of course, the icons a little more tiny. The annoying thing is that the Start button does *not* get smaller like the icons do and it sticks out and covers up part of whatever is beneath it.

Is there a way to make *not* cover things up/be smaller?

[image: Example]

Comment: The use of third-party software would be required.

Answer (score 2):

#### Is there a way to make the start button not cover things up/be smaller?

You will need to use a 3rd party product, for example [Classic Start Menu](http://www.classicshell.net/features/).

The Start Button is configurable, with both built in buttons and the possibility to use a user defined button.

You can see the Start Button settings at the bottom of this dialog:

[image: http://www.classicshell.net/features/]

Here is my taskbar:

[image: ![enter image description here]

#### Disclaimer

I am not affiliated with [Classic Shell](http://www.classicshell.net/) with in any way, I am just an end user of their software.